# IndentationError message Django

Tags: django, indentation

I am working with Django 1.4.2 and I got the following error message:

[image] Can someone tell me which files are having the indent problem? I tried 
`python -m tabnanny -v manage.py` and I got "Clean bill of health" so I think that file is alright.
And I have never touched the other 2 files before.

I am working with Python 2.7.2 and Django 1.4.2 on Vista.

Here's the entire importlibs.py:

```
def _resolve_name(name, package, level):
"""Return the absolute name of the module to be imported."""
if not hasattr(package, 'rindex'):
    raise ValueError("'package' not set to a string")
dot = len(package)
for x in xrange(level, 1, -1):
    try:
        dot = package.rindex('.', 0, dot)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("attempted relative import beyond top-level "
                          "package")
return "%s.%s" % (package[:dot], name)

def import_module(name, package=None):
"""Import a module.

The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
relative import to an absolute import.

"""
if name.startswith('.'):
    if not package:
        raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
    level = 0
    for character in name:
        if character != '.':
            break
        level += 1
    name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
__import__(name) # LINE 35
return sys.modules[name]
```

Comment: It's not any of the Django files. It's one of the files in your project.

Comment: @Daniel Can we tell which one just from the error message? I tried `tabnanny -v <files>` for all my project files and all output the "Clean bill of health" message.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, it does seem as if it's django/utils/importlib.py that's having the problem. Can't imagine why.

Comment: If the problem is in a django file they try deleting django and reinstalling it. If this does not solve the problem then it likely has nothing to do with importlib. Also what code editor are you using?

Comment: You may also want to check new lines `\n` versus `\r\n` in the django as well as your files.

Comment: Did you mess around with this importlibs file? because I can see clear indentation problems in the code you provided which shouldn't be there. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/importlib.py

Comment: Are you sure you are "python -m tabnanny -v manage.py" is doing what you think it should be doing? I think what that command is doing is checking for indentation problems in the file "manage.py" however the indentation error is likely somewhere else in the code. I would try doing something like "python -m tabnanny -v DjangoTutorial2" as the indentation is likely not from the stdlib

Answer (score 0):

Using tab in Django is a bad practice. In order to fixed your problem you must use spaces only, I think 4 spaces. Try to backspace your codes and you'll see that it's tab indention, use only spaces.